# Автоматическое воспроизведение видео после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, видео

Как добавить видео на сайт, чтобы оно автоматически запускалось без пользователя, например как на сайте https://morgenshterntour.ru? Через какие ЯП это делается или это можно через верстку?

Comment: посмотрите: http://htmlbook.ru/html/video/autoplay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если говорится о видео фоне то достаточно html и css и в качестве атрибутов к тегу видео добавить `autoplay muted preload`

Пример оформлениия видео как фона у header: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/oNjpqZE

```css
div.body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

video {
  display: block;
  min-width: 110vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -10px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <video autoplay muted preload>
   <source src="https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/landings-video/Backend.webm" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  <div class="play"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не уверен, что такая ссылка не умрёт через несколько дней

Comment: @andreymal я вообще не знаю где брать ссылки на видосы для демонстрации

Comment: @MaximLensky Как ты такую ссылку сделал и где их вообще брать? Я просто только начинающий и вообще не в чем не разбираюсь

Comment: @DaniilApekalovsky надо видео скачать просто и указать путь (src) у тебя в проекте, вот щас к примеру ссылка не рабочая

Comment: @andreymal, она уже умерла.

Comment: @MaximLensky, у w3c есть видео с кроликом - тащи его.

Answer (score 8):

Атрибут `autoplay` - при наличии этого атрибута видео воспроизводится автоматически после загрузки страницы. Кроме этого, крайне важно также добавить и атрибут `muted`, иначе в некоторых браузерах автоматического воспроизведения не будет.

```html
<video width="420" height="240" controls autoplay muted id="videoId">
  <source src="https://whatsaper.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/whatsaper.ru-9-мая-день-победы.-Видео-поздравления..mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
```

Comment: Правильно. И важно не забыть `muted`, иначе некоторые браузеры не станут автоматически играть видео.

Comment: Там есть ещё атрибут, который говорит браузеру, что видео - это фон.

Comment: @Qwertiy, какой атрибут, я его не встречал и щас не нашел... Будь другом подскажи...

Comment: @Air, если б я помнил, я бы сразу написал...

Comment: @Qwertiy,  OK................